# C# локальная сеть для нескольких устройств

Tags: c#, unity3d, сеть

Пишу проект на Unity, в силу определенных ограничений нет возможности использовать встроенные средства юнити для сетевой игры. Поэтому пишу свое.

В общем есть сервер:

```
class Server : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start(){
        listener = new TcpListener(8080);
        listener.Start();

        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Service));
        t.Start();
    }

    void Service(){
        while(true){
            Socket soc = listener.AcceptSocket();
            Debug.Log("Connected: " + soc.RemoteEndPoint);

            try{
                Stream s = new NetworkStream(soc); 
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s);
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s);
                sw.AutoFlush = true;
                // do something
                s.Close();
            } catch(Exception e){
                Debug.Log(e.Message);
            }
            Debug.Log("Disconnected: " + soc.RemoteEndPoint);
            soc.Close();
        }
    }

    void OnGUI () {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (System.Net.IPAddress ip in System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList) 
        {
            GUI.Label (new Rect (0,i*50,100,(i+1)*50), ip.ToString());
            ++i;
        }
    }
}
```

И есть клиент

```
class Client : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        try{
            client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 8080);
            s = client.GetStream();
            sr = new StreamReader(s);
            sw = new StreamWriter(s);
            sw.AutoFlush = true;
        } catch (Exception e){
            Debug.Log(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Общая задача - подключиться и переслать данные.

Когда я запускаю и сервер, и клиент на компьютере, то все работает - клиент подключается, данные передаются (причем работает с `127.0.0.1` и с любым локальным ip из тех, что выводятся в `onGUI`)

Когда же я запускаю сервер на компьютере, а подключаться пытаюсь с телефона на андроиде (или наоборот), то постоянно получаю ошибку во время подключения из серии "не подключился, потому что время истекло".

При этом компьютер и телефон находятся в одной локальной сети (пробовал подключать и через usb, и через usb в режиме модема, и раздавал с телефона вайфай, подключаясь к нему с компьютера - во всех случаях одно и то же).

Кто сталкивался, как бороться, как подключаться (задача передать данные с устройства А на устройство Б внутри одной локальной сети)?

Comment: Я не фанат андроида и про него не скажу. Но, ведь должен быть роутер для соединения устройств. Вы открыли порты в брендмауэре\фаерволле в Windows? Вы пробросили порты в роутере (Port Forwarding)?